# Check if a vector contains object with already entered values

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, structure, istream

so I'm struggling with these things:

I have method that returns istream input and takes istream input as a parameter, sends values to vector and stores them in it. Now, when I've entered 1 value, I'm trying to make a check if vector already contains that value, here is my code to understand it better:

```
struct Predmet {
    string naziv;
    string odsjek;
    istream& dodaj_predmet(istream &);
};

struct Student {
    string brojIndeksa;
    string ime;
    string prezime;
    map<std::string, int> ocjene;
    istream& dodaj_studenta(istream &);
};

vector<Student> studenti;
vector<Predmet> predmeti;
Student s;
Predmet p;

istream& Student::dodaj_studenta(istream & input){
    cout << "### Unesite podatke o studentu: " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Unesite broj indeksa studenta: " << endl;
    getline(input, brojIndeksa);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Unesite ime studenta: " << endl;
    getline(input, ime);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Unesite prezime studenta: " << endl;
    getline(input, prezime);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "***     Uspjesno ste unijeli studenta     ***" << endl;
    return input;
}
```

So I'm trying to make a check if value entered for structure member `brojIndeksa` already exists in vector, and I'm not sure how to do it.

Also how can I add values to map, because I need to add pair<string, int>, and not sure how, because I need to check if `STRING` is a value entered in `naziv` inside `predmeti` vector?

Thanks.

Comment: `std::find` or `std::find_if` will help: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Comment: Already tried with both of them, but got the same error for both them, so I'm not sure if I'm passing the right arguments.

Comment: please show a [mre] with what you've tried and the error you encountered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, you can check count of std::vector to see if given key exists

```cpp
//std::count(v.begin(), v.end(), key)
if (std::count(v.begin(), v.end(), key)){
    //it is inside
}
else{
    //it isn't inside
}
```

This is one way to go, but you should do the map

```cpp
std::map<std::string,int> myMap;
//adding will look like this
std::pair<std::string,int> element;
myMap.insert(element);
//or
myMap.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>(myString,myInt));
```

Will solve your problem. You add pair of string and int.
In order to check if given key exists you can do

```cpp
std::map<std::string, int> m;
if ( m.find(key) == m.end() ) {
  // not found
} else {
  // found
}
```

Added Kyle comment to, as it is valid way, and it looks a bit cleaner, you can also find if element exists like this

```cpp
if (m.count(key)){
    //key found
}
else{
    //key not found
}
```

PS. It's bad practice to use `c++ using namespace std;`. You should always use `std::whatever_you_need` instead

Comment: Both `map` and `set` also have a `count` function that can be used to check for the existence of a key/element. It's a bit less repetitive to use if you don't intend to use the iterator returned by `find` (`m.count(key) != 0` instead of `m.count(key) != m.end()`).

Comment: @Jarod42 std::map<std::string, int> im sorry i just added explanation

Answer (score 1):

For your first question regard checking for a Student: you can add this search after the input.

```cpp
    auto clean_buf = input.rdbuf()
    ....
    auto resit = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), 
                 [&](auto& student) { 
                   return ( student.brojIndeska == brojIndeska)
                 });
    if(resit != v.end()) {//student exists
      input.rdbuf(clean_buf);
      return input;
     }
```

For the second, you can add to a map using

```
map.emplace(var1, var2)
```

Comment: Ok looks like this worked for me, thank you. Just 1 more question, how to get out of function now and call another function? Like if brIndeksa exists I need to go back to main menu, but when I do it it still prints out lines for other data input (ime, prezime).

Comment: You can set it up as an if else block. So, if resit is not equal to v.end(), i.e. the student exists, then return the current input or even tack on an error saying the student exists. If you don't care about the input and you just want to reset to the original buffer, you can save istream.rdbuf() at the start and reset it before returning early. I'll try and add a snippet in my answer above.

Comment: I don't need my input after it throws an error, I just want it to start again from beginning so input can be deleted.

Comment: Sounds like you need a loop to go through the input then.  I would think this belongs outside of your struct though

Comment: Let me try to explain it a bit more. So, when check throws an error (if entered value already exists in Student structure), I just want the function to stop executing, I've tried returning value of my function, but it still keeps going and executing the rest of the function. How can I stop it from executing, and just call another function and start over with my already entered data?

Comment: I posted an edit to my original code that will exit the function. I don't know what else to tell you

Comment: Well if you have nested functions, if i undestand you right, you can return some value and check it after call of that function. For example ```int fun(int k){ if (k) return 0; else return 1;} ``` And it caller function you can do something like ```if (fun(k)) { return;}```. You use string instead so see which value is impossible to have and put that value

Comment: @Dusan yes, but based on the code the OP posted, i have no idea how he is interfacing with the structs. His code was sufficient for the original questions, but insufficient regarding his comment of exiting early and continuing on.

Comment: @sucksatnetworking yes, i just wrote basic universal way. He should add some minimum code for replicating